# keyboard shortcuts to select text from terminal in zsh shell?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, terminal, zsh

Wanted to select text while writing in the current line or want to select some of the text from the outputs of the previous commands.
I'm using the normal terminal of macOs catalina 10.15.5.

Seems to be not possible from the `bash` shell. Just wanted to confirm if there is any option for `zsh` to do this.

Referred [this](https://superuser.com/questions/125190/select-text-from-terminal-app-using-the-keyboard-in-os-x) question before.
Also, one of the answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15753523/in-the-terminal-on-mac-osx-how-to-use-shift-arrows-in-order-to-select-text) question doesn't seem to be working for zsh.

Comment: There is support for an emacs style region with emacs key bindings ot vim visual mode using vi key bindings. Neither of those are the Windows-like shift plus cursors and integration with a desktop clipboard may be limited without plugins using pbcopy or the OSC 52 escape sequence.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of different ways you can select and/or copy the output from a previous command in macOS's Terminal app:

- You can press <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> to select the last command's output. (Provided that **Edit > Marks > Automatically Mark Prompt Lines** is enabled, which it is, by default.)
- You can simply use the mouse to select text.
- You can copy a command's output by piping it to macOS's `pbcopy` command:

  ```sh
  echo test | pbcopy
  ```